# How to get 2nd generation cloud functions URI in Terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, terraform

I am trying to deploy a Cloud Workflow on Google Cloud which sends HTTPS requests to trigger second generation cloud functions.

The problem is, that as of now, according to [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/create-deploy-gcloud) you can not determine the URI of a second generation cloud function in advance.

> Note: Currently, function URLs in Cloud Functions (2nd gen) use a non-deterministic format, meaning you cannot predict your function URL before deployment, though the URL remains stable after deployment. In a future release, function URLs will be updated to be both stable and deterministic.

I have tried to obtain the URI via the following gcloud command:

`gcloud functions describe FUNCTION_NAME`

However, this solution is not optimal for me, because Cloud Workflow does not support gcloud commands and I have to build it manually every time.

This is my code snippet:

```
resource "google_workflows_workflow" "my-workflow" {

  ...

  source_contents = <<-EOT
  main:
    steps:
      - step_1:
          try:
            call: http.get
            args:
                url: https://test-function-212jbj1-ew.a.run.app
                timeout: 1800
                auth:
                    type: OIDC
            result: resp
  EOT
}
```

Is there a way to get second generation Cloud Function URI dynamically without hard-coding like shown above?

Comment: Not yet, the team is actively working to transform the hash in a deterministic generation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to avoid hard-coding and insert the 2nd Generation Cloud Function(or Cloud Run) URL dynamically, **after their creation**. Cloud Run uses a unique identifier/hash in the URL, the generation algorithm of which [can be subject to change](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/triggering/https-request#creating_public_services) and since 2nd generation Cloud Functions are provided by Cloud Run, the same applies to them. However, by using [depends_on argument in terraform](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/depends_on), we can ensure that our resource is created before the Workflow(or any other service we might want to pass the URL to) and then retrieve the URL of the created Cloud Function:

```
resource "google_cloudfunctions2_function" "my-function" {
  ...
}


resource "google_workflows_workflow" "my-workflow" {
    depends_on = [
        google_cloudfunctions2_function.my-function
    ]

    ...

    source_contents = <<-EOT
    main:
      steps:
        - step_1:
            try:
              call: http.get
              args:
                  url:  ${google_cloudfunctions2_function.my-function.service_config[0].uri}
                  timeout: 1800
                  auth:
                      type: OIDC
              result: resp
    EOT
}
```

Same can be achieved for Cloud Run resources as well:

```
google_cloud_run_service.your-cloud-run-resource-name.status[0].url
```

Comment: I can't believe how easily this worked. Thanks so much!